# how to pass mock location from junit test to Activity in Android

Tags: android, junit

I am having an activity which prints in a textView any changes in location. I want to test it wit JUnit. here is my code and here is my output:

```
public void testGPS() {
        {
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) myActivity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            String testProvider = "Test";

            if (null == lm.getProvider(testProvider)) {
                lm.addTestProvider(testProvider, false, false, false, false,
                        false, false, false, Criteria.POWER_LOW,
                        Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            }

            lm.setTestProviderEnabled(testProvider, true);
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(testProvider, 0, 0,
                    myActivity.mLocListener);
            lm.setTestProviderStatus(testProvider, LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,
                    null, System.currentTimeMillis());

            // getService().setUpProvider(testProvider,lm)

            Location location = new Location(testProvider);
            location.setLatitude(1.0);
            location.setLongitude(2.0);
            location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            lm.setTestProviderLocation(testProvider, location);

            String test_rs = "lon=" + location.getLongitude() + "\nlat="
                    + location.getLatitude();
            String msg = "Location Succeeded";
            // Assert.assertFalse("Received Location is null", received == null
            // );
            assertEquals(msg, myActivity.mTextLocation.getText().toString(),
                    test_rs);

            lm.removeTestProvider(testProvider);
        }
```

and the trace is:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: Location Succeeded expected:<Unknown> but was:<lon=2.0
lat=1.0>
at mypackage.TestActivity.testGPS(TestActivity.java:73)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:204)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:194)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:186)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)
```

So as you can see here:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: Location Succeeded expected:<Unknown> but was:<lon=2.0 lat=1.0>.
```

So it is like myMain Activity does not get the location from my test.

Any help?

EDIT: myActivity is the activity I want to test. Line 73 is the assert. I just want to pass a location to the activity from the test. How to do it?

Comment: You testing this in an emulator or real device with GPS support? What is myActivity? And which line is TestActivity.java:73? Also as a side comment, JUnit is not used like this. The test should test modules of your Activity, not rewrite the code in here. So you have to actually call code on your Activity that does this.

Comment: myActivity is the activity I want to test. Line 73 is the assert. I just want to pass a location to the activity from the test. How to do it?

Comment: Write a `setLocation()` method for the test. Also are you testing on emulator or real device?

Comment: What do you mean by Setlocation()? Can you give me an example? I am testing on real device.

Comment: If you want to pass a Location to the Activity, write a `public void setLocation(Location location)` method in your Activity, and call this method from your test.

Comment: As you can see from my code is to pass it using the location listener of my activity.

Comment: Ok I see, sorry. Then I think you're not waiting enough for your listener to get the location update. Try inserting a Thread.sleep() or better, make your test thread wait for Activity listener to be called.

Comment: but I am sending the new location, why should I wait?

Comment: As far as I understand, you are sending a location to compare with the real location.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get this to work, at least for me.

The clues are here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html

> ...you don't have to disable or remove test code before you publish.

... and ...

> Always set the provider value to flp, which is the code that Location Services puts into the Location objects it sends out.

I also found that it's necessary to give the update time to be delivered.

So, here's what I ended up with:

```
public void testGPS() {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) mActivity
        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    lm.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);
    lm.setTestProviderStatus(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                             LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,
                             null, System.currentTimeMillis());

    Location location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    location.setLatitude(1.0);
    location.setLongitude(2.0);
    location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    lm.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, location);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you allow the permission for access_mock_location in your manifest file? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" /> I get a securityexception.

Comment: This was a few years ago now, but yes, I'm fairly sure I did have to add that permission.